# changing the path to which pv is pointing

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want to change the path to which the following pv is pointing. I am using Elasticsearch helm chart provided by elastic.coRefer to the below ss.

Here I am providing the link to the [statefulset.yaml](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/main/elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml).

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include enough detail in the question itself to answer the question?  "How can I move a persistent volume" seems like a little more like a system-administration question than a programming question and this might be more appropriate on a different site.

Comment: feel free to add more details and clarity question, voting for close. you can directly edit the PV if just changing path your requirement not sure was concern you have ? `kubectl edit pv` that might could break pvc or other resources so make sure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HarshManvar kubectl edit pv is not working in my case , it is not allowing to change the path. I t is showing the following error:                               error: persistentvolumes "pvc-c2ed061c-4ace-498c-9ef5-9e5151f75fa5" is invalid
A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-2012951018.yaml"
error: Edit cancelled, no valid changes were saved.